# How to hide the # in the base URL using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, routes

Is it possible to hide the `#` in the URL when using Angular routing, but only for the base URL ?

I know it's possible to use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to remove the `#`, but I want to keep the `#` for others routes.

For exemple, with the following Angular module :

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);

sampleApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/index.html'
      }).
      when('/addItem', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/addItem.html'
      }).          
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
});
```

Currently, when I go to `mysite.com`, I get the URL `mysite.com/#/`, but I want to get a clean URL without `#`.

I cant use `html5Mode` because I want to have the URL `mysite.com/#/addItem` also.

Comment: # -> hashtag -> uri fragment is part of the SPA, if you don't have "a new .html" browsers use the fragment (#) to set in how section you are, and in this case, angular uses that with the routeProvider. So in my opinion, if you are writing a SPA, no, you can't get a clean URL if you are not using another .html

Comment: It's my opinion too, but maybe a particular config, or a special version of Angular $route can do what I want.